# Explicit cast causing NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure why two of my Java libraries are having difficulty playing nicely together.  Here is the scenario:

Library 1 has a class A with the following constructor:

```
public A(Object obj) { /* boilerplate */ }
```

In a previous version, A's constructor was:

```
public A(Serializable s) { /* more or less same boilerplate */ }
```

Now library 2 was built against the previous version, and constructs an instance of A:

```
A myObject = new A( (Serializable) arg);
```

When libraries 1 (the newest version) and 2 are deployed together, the constructor invocation throws a NoSuchMethodError, and the stack trace explains that the JVM is looking for a constructor with a Serializable argument.

It seems to me that all object instances are castable to Object, even if explicitly cast to an interface during an invocation.  However this experiment has proven otherwise.  For posterity, can anyone elaborate on what rule of Java is causing the NoSuchMethodError to appear?  I would greatly appreciate a specification citation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method that gets called by `new A(...)` is resolved when library 2 is compiled, and its signature is stored in library 2's class file.

If you compile library 2 against the old version of library 1, the bytecode for `A myObject = new A( (Serializable) arg)` would look something like:

```
   9:   new #1;     //class A
   12:  aload_1     //arg
   13:  invokespecial   #24; //Method "<init>":(Ljava/io/Serializable;)V
```

If the method with this signature no longer exists when this code is invoked, you get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: Really?  So the actual signature of the linked library is written into the compiled bytecode?  Wow.

Comment: @jordan002: That's how I understand it, and is what the above decompile indicates.

Comment: Clearly I'm talking to the right person.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are overloaded (not overridden) and bounded at compile time.

So lib2 is looking for A(Serializable), but there is only an A(Object).